Python code to connect Snowflake showing ERROR at line "password=os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE'].encode() "
I am trying to connect to snowflake using RSA but getting below error, I have tried with working code from online but still same error. I am not sure if I missed anything.
Error Message:
C:/Users/Prabhakar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe d:/Snowflake/Learning/Python/VSO/Sample1.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\\Snowflake\\Learning\\Python\\VSO\\Sample1.py", line 21, in \<module\>
password=os.environ\['PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE'\].encode(),
\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File " frozen os \>", line 714, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE'

import os
import logging
import snowflake.connector
 
for logger_name in ['snowflake.connector', 'botocore', 'boto3']:
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.FileHandler('/ingest.log')
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(funcName)s() - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(ch)
 
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
 
with open("RSA/rsa_key.p8", "rb") as key:
    p_key= serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key.read(),
        password=os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE'].encode(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )
 
pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())
 
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
   private_key=pkb,    
   user='PRABHA',
    account='ul72225',
    warehouse='LEARNING',
    database='PRABHADEV',
    schema='DBO'
    )
 
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()

text
I followed all steps to configure RSA and everything is fine but python code is throwing error. Above code is someone else code which was working for them and even if I use same code it's throwing same error

The variable PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE is not present in the environment.  Show us how you are setting this variable.

I have no idea, I am new to Python (learning state)
I am trying to connect to Snowflake via using RSA. SO, I have seen couple of code online and every where they use similar code and I haven't seen anyone specifying some value to PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE in the code

I have tried to define PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE with Passphrase value which I used in openssl but still I am getting same error
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE = 'snowflakersa'

That's because PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE is not specified in the code, it's specified in the environment.

@Prabha, can you try printing the value of PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE in the Python script?  Then you can verify if it's outputting 'snowflakersa'? If not, then as mentioned, you might not be setting in the environment of the script.
e.g.
on Linux/macOS: export PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE='snowflakersa' ...then run your script.
